# How to force GWT to add unique ID to each DOM element?

Tags: gwt

I am having a GWT app,
I would like to add ID to each element automaticlly
if it's impossible, what would be the fastest way to do it manually?

Comment: What is your use case? You don't need to add ids to elements in GWT unless you use an external JavaScript. Adding id to each element will negatively impact the performance.

Comment: How will that help external JS? Why can't the external JS add its own IDs as it needs them?

Comment: the external JS needs to manipulate the DOM that GWT created..

Comment: You can manipulate that DOM without any IDs, or with only some IDs. If all IDs are generated, (i.e. auto-1, auto-2, auto-3) they may be different from page load to page load, or when every anything in the gwt app changes, breaking any assumptions the external JS makes. Better to assign classnames, or find another way to solve this. Can you describe the actual problem you are trying to solve? You're seem to be asking "How do I drive a fence post with a hammer?" when what you really need to ask is "How to I build a wooden fence?"

Answer (score 3):

I am not so sure about performance issues. How would adding a dew ids in a form of 10-20 widgets cause performance loss?

To automagically set debug ids on widgets you need to include following in your module.gwt.xml file.

```
<!-- Enable debug ID. -->
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.Debug"/>
<set-property name="gwt.enableDebugId" value="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes its Possible :

First way:

```java
Button b = new Button();
DOM.setElementAttribute(b.getElement(), "id", "my-button-id")
```

Second way :

```java
FlowPanel panel = new FlowPanel();
panel.getElement().setId("my-flowpanel-id");
```

If you want to do assign all the id's attached to DOM  you can do

```java
Iterator<Widget> iterator = RootPanel.get().iterator();

while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    Widget w = iterator.next();
     w.getElement().setId("id");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own Widget class that extends GWT Widget and sets an id to each one:

```java
public class myWidget extends Widget {

    public myWidget(String id) {
        super();
        getElement().setId("id");
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        // Use this method if you use Ui:Binder
        getElement().setId("id");
    }
}
```

You can, obviously, extend other classes instead of Widget if you don't need id on all widgets, like FlowPanel, Button, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have an element to have an Id always, you can go with [ensureDebugId](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html#ensureDebugId%28com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element,%20java.lang.String%29) of UI Object class. It make sure that, your element have an Id set before attaching it to the dom.